# Prestashop - give user ability to upload custom image for product

Tags: prestashop

How can this be achieved in Prestashop version 1.4.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add personalization to the product.
In BO edit product, choose 6th tab (personalization, customize - i don't know how its on english - i have polish version) and then add one field Files Type and click update.
Then give this field name, choose is this field is required and save all.
I thinkg that should be enought

Answer (score 2):

I know its bit of late but here is my answer
go to Products page under Catalog option and select edit product, then click on Customization and Select File Type or Text Type to upload an image and its description directly from prestashop.